# How to implement Java methods in Nativescript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, ffmpeg, nativescript

I'm having trouble calling some methods of an Android java library for ffmpeg. I think I successfuly loaded the library because I can console.log the library object:

```
JS: BuildConfig -> function () { [native code] }
JS: ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler -> function () { [native code] }
JS: FFmpeg -> function () { [native code] }
JS: FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler -> function () { [native code] }
JS: FFmpegLoadBinaryResponseHandler -> function () { [native code] }
JS: LoadBinaryResponseHandler -> function () { [native code] }
```

[This is the code I want to "translate" (under Usage)](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java)

This is how far I got ([using this nativescript guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface.html)) :

```js
// [...]

var MyCustomLoadBinaryResponseHandler = 
com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg
.LoadBinaryResponseHandler.extend({
  onStart: function() {
    console.log('Started loading ffmpeg');
  },
  onFailure: function() {
    console.log('Failed loading ffmpeg');
  },
  onSuccess: function() {
    console.log('Successfully loaded ffmpeg');
  },
  onFinish: function() {
    console.log('Finished loading ffmpeg');
  }
});

console.dir(MyCustomLoadBinaryResponseHandler);
//^ this logs the following
//~ JS: === dump(): dumping members ===
//~ JS: "()function () { [native code] }"
//~ JS: === dump(): dumping function and properties names ===
//~ JS: extend()
//~ JS: null()
//~ JS: === dump(): finished ===

var context = app.android.context;

var ffmpeg = 
com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg.getInstance(context);

console.dir(ffmpeg);
//^ this logs the following
//~ JS: === dump(): dumping members ===
//~ JS: {
//~ JS:     "constructor": "constructor()function () { [native code] 
//}"
//~ JS: }
//~ JS: === dump(): dumping function and properties names ===
//~ JS: constructor()
//~ JS: concatenate()
//~ JS: execute()
//~ JS: getDeviceFFmpegVersion()
//~ JS: getLibraryFFmpegVersion()
//~ JS: isFFmpegCommandRunning()
//~ JS: killRunningProcesses()
//~ JS: loadBinary()
//~ JS: setTimeout()
//~ JS: <init>()
//~ JS: clone()
//~ JS: equals()
//~ JS: finalize()
//~ JS: getClass()
//~ JS: hashCode()
//~ JS: notify()
//~ JS: notifyAll()
//~ JS: toString()
//~ JS: wait()
//~ JS: === dump(): finished ===


ffmpeg.loadBinary(
  new MyCustomLoadBinaryResponseHandler()
);

var MyCustomExecuteBinaryResponseHandler = 
com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg
.ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler.extend({
  onStart: function() {
    console.log('Started running ffmpeg');
  },
  onProgress: function(thisMessage) {
    console.log(' ffmpeg running');
    console.log(thisMessage);
  },
  onFailure: function(thisMessage) {
    console.log('Failed running ffmpeg');
    console.log(thisMessage);
  },
  onSuccess: function(thisMessage) {
    console.log('Successfully run ffmpeg');
    console.log(thisMessage);
  },
  onFinish: function() {
    console.log('Finished running ffmpeg');
  }
});

//this is where it crashes
ffmpeg.execute('-version', new 
MyCustomExecuteBinaryResponseHandler());
```

Unfortunately, the whole app crashes with no error message the app and I can't continue unless I have more information on what is going on. Am I implementing the methods in a wrong way? How do you suggest I continue?

edit: these are the last logs on the console

```
09-06 11:22:58.884 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[])
09-06 11:22:58.884 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
09-06 11:22:58.884 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1043)
09-06 11:22:58.884 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:925)
09-06 11:22:58.884 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:912)
09-06 11:22:58.884 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:896)
09-06 11:22:58.884 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:888)
09-06 11:22:59.021 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
09-06 11:22:59.021 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1043)
09-06 11:22:59.021 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:925)
09-06 11:22:59.021 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:912)
09-06 11:22:59.021 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:896)
09-06 11:22:59.021 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:888)
09-06 11:22:59.022 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native method)
09-06 11:22:59.022 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1043)
09-06 11:22:59.022 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:925)
09-06 11:22:59.022 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:912)
09-06 11:22:59.022 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:896)
09-06 11:22:59.022 31522 31522 F art     : art/runtime/runtime.cc:403]   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:888)
```

Comment: If you don't see an error activity, then it's a JNI exception which can only be traced in the ADB Logcat. However this might find better answers in the nativescript forums. Additionally, sharing a repository where the problem can be reproduced would be ideal.

Comment: Actually to be specific there are messages on the console,  JNI exceptions maybe as you suggested? I will include them in the question

Comment: I haven't used this recently but you should be able to generate  Type definitions for your library. I find having type definitions helpful when working with Native libraries in NativeScript 
https://github.com/NativeScript/android-dts-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the sample github repository https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/hiteshsondhi88/sampleffmpeg/Home.java#L80

the `execute` method accepts a string collection/array as its first parameter. Therefore your code should look like:

```
ffmpeg.execute(['-version'], new MyCustomExecuteBinaryResponseHandler());
```

Comment: Indeed this was the problem! The crash is gone after building again and the handlers actually log information, as well as the ffmpeg output. Thank you very much!